# left-align long equation in enumerate outside of item

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align, indentation

I have a long equation in an enumerate environment that starts left-aligned with the numerical item (which is indented). I tried `\noindent`-ing the equation outside of the `\begin{align}`, but it didn't work. Example:

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item 
\begin{align}
R(x) = really-long-equation-that-gets-forced-to-align-with-the-number-1.-but-I-want-full-left-alignment
\end{align}
\end{enumerate}
```

Comment: What you want is not clear. Is it the indentation of the item number that you don't want? or the indentation of the equation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start the display with `\hspace{-\leftmargin}`:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\noindent
Text
\begin{enumerate}
\item
  \begin{align}
  \hspace{-\leftmargin}
    R(x) = really-long-equation-that-gets-forced-to-align-with-the-number-1.-but-I-want-full-left-alignment
\end{align}
  \item Text.
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[strict]{changepage}
%%------------ for restoring textwidth inside list, for equations
\makeatletter
    \newsavebox\restorebox
\newenvironment{restoretext}%
    {\@parboxrestore%
        \begin{adjustwidth}{}{}%
                \begin{lrbox}{\restorebox}%
                \hspace{\dimexpr\labelwidth-\labelsep\relax}%
                \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth-\labelwidth\relax}%
    }{\end{minipage}\end{lrbox}
        \usebox\restorebox
        \end{adjustwidth}
     }
\makeatother
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item   \lipsum*[11]
\begin{restoretext}
\begin{gather}
R(x) = really-long-equation-that-gets-forced-to-align-with-the-number-1.-but-I-want-full-left-alignment
\end{gather}
\end{restoretext}
\item   \lipsum*[11]
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

if you like that lef side of equation star at left text border, than change definition for `restoretext` change to

```
\newenvironment{restoretext}%
    {\@parboxrestore%
        \begin{adjustwidth}{}{}%
                \begin{lrbox}{\restorebox}%
                \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}%
    }{\end{minipage}\end{lrbox}
        \usebox\restorebox
        \end{adjustwidth}
     }
```

of course, so long equation (wider than paper width) can not be fit in text width. if it is really so long than you should consider to break it in two (or if it is necessary) more lines.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want this, which can be obtained in two ways: with the  `adjustwidth` environment (from `changepage`), or leaving the `enumerate` environment, inserting the maths in full text width, and resuming  `enumerate` afterwards withe `resume] option of`enumitem`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{changepage} 

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item 
\begin{adjustwidth}{-\leftmargini}{0cm}
\begin{align}
R(x) = \text{really-long-equation-that-gets-forced-to-align-with-the-number-1.-but-I-want-full-left-alignment}
\end{align}
\end{adjustwidth}
\item Another item.
\end{enumerate}
\vskip1cm

\begin{enumerate}[after = \leavevmode\vspace*{-\abovedisplayskip}]
\item
\end{enumerate}
\begin{align}
R(x) = \text{really-long-equation-that-gets-forced-to-align-with-the-number-1.-but-I-want-full-left-alignment}
\end{align}
\begin{enumerate}[resume]
\item Another item.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]