# Pgfplots: Calling a defined style to create repeat instances of coordinate plane

Tags: pgfplots, tikz-styles

The mwe below contains a wonderful (for me) defined style that creates a coordinate plane for my students use in graphing systems of equations. @JasperHabicht created this code to avoid having to repeatedly copy/paste the original style code lines.

```
\pgfplotsset{
    my axis format/.style={
        axis lines=middle,
        axis line style={
            -stealth,
            shorten >=-3mm
        },
```

Please assist this tex novice with the proper code to call this style for successive math problems created by `\task` in a 2 column worksheet format.

Many thanks for taking time to respond!

mwe:

````
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\pgfplotsset{
    my axis format/.style={
        axis lines=middle,
        axis line style={
            -stealth,
            shorten >=-3mm
        },
        axis equal,
        xmin=-8, xmax=8,
        ymin=-8, ymax=8,
        width=10cm,
        height=10cm,
        xlabel=$x$,
        ylabel=$y$,
        grid=both,
        grid style={
            draw=gray!25
        },
        xtick={-10,-9,...,10}, 
        xtick style={
            yshift=-0.5ex, 
        },
        xticklabel style={
            font=\scriptsize\color{blue}
        },
        ytick={-10,-9,...,10}, 
        ytick style={
            xshift=-0.5ex
        },
        yticklabel style={
            font=\scriptsize\color{blue}
        },
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        my axis format
    ]
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document} ```
````

Comment: It is not entirely clear what you after, sory. It seems that you may looking for somethin like what is proposed in my answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/683292/pgfplots-need-to-force-left-two-coordinate-planes-to-avoid-right-hand-bleed. There is common style for all diagrams which call `GRID` axis style.

Comment: @Zarko Thanks for your very helpful edits to my OP. Since I don't see the edits reflected in the OP, does that mean I should manually enter those revisions? As for the worksheet I need, this link should demonstrate. The problem will have 10 - 12 separate problems to graph. https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DTpB.png

Comment: @Zarko   I want to avoid cluttering the code with repeated iterations of the 15 code lines that start with ```\begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            axis lines=middle,```

Comment: Please, carefully inspect/study my code in given link again. It exactly do, what you after: remove all clutter. If something is not clear or you need more explanation, wrote a comment to this answer.

Comment: @Zarko  How ironic....I'm always admonishing my high school students to the directions more carefully. And here I'm the worst offender. Thanks to you, I see now "call" code = ```begin{restoretext}  \begin{tikzpicture}  \begin{axis}[GRID] ```
  **What does the command ```restoretext``` do? ** Never encountered that command before.

Comment: Huh, I use it it very long time, so I forgot where I find source for `\@parboxrestore`, on which is based definition of `restoretext` environment in my answer preamble. Sorry. I think now that it is from TeX or LaTeX kernel. It from "itemize box" restore "text box" which size is than determined by `adjustwidth` macro. For more detailed/correct answer i need to investigated my (very) old solutions and check/search this site. So far is more important if this my answer solve your problem and if liked, that I wrote here some explanation, how it works.

Comment: @Zarko Thanks for your response! I agree that it "is more important if my answer solves your problem". I up-voted your original response. If your interest, here's a link code using ```restoretext``` https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/411914/left-align-long-equation-in-enumerate-outside-of-item

Comment: Oh, meanwhile I already wrote an answer :-). Hopefully is sufficient clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In cases, when in document are number of `pgfplots` diagrams whit the same settings of `axis˛environments, you can merge this settings in one, common style, for example (taken from my answer on your [previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/683292/pgfplots-need-to-force-left-two-coordinate-planes-to-avoid-right-hand-bleed)):

```
\pgfplotsset{GRID/.style = {    % define common style for images
    width=100mm,
    axis lines=middle,
    axis line style={-stealth,shorten >=-3mm},
    xlabel=$x$, xlabel style={anchor=south west},
    ylabel=$y$, ylabel style={anchor=south east},
    grid=both,
    grid style={draw=gray!25},
    ticklabel style={font=\scriptsize, text=black!50, inner sep=1pt},
    xmin=-10,   xmax=10,
    ymin=-10,   ymax=10,
    xtick distance=2,
    ytick distance=2,
    minor tick num=1,
    tick align=outside,
            }}
```

and then in document use as

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[GRID]
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

Of course you can style name "GRID" change to whatever you like to have and what has more meaning to you.

In cases when all diagrams have the same `axis` style, then you not need top name axis style, sufficient is to add definition to `\pgfplotsset`:

```
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18,
    width=100mm,
    axis lines=middle,
    axis line style={-stealth,shorten >=-3mm},
    xlabel=$x$, xlabel style={anchor=south west},
    ylabel=$y$, ylabel style={anchor=south east},
    grid=both,
    grid style={draw=gray!25},
    ticklabel style={font=\scriptsize, text=black!50, inner sep=1pt},
    xmin=-10,   xmax=10,
    ymin=-10,   ymax=10,
    xtick distance=2,
    ytick distance=2,
    minor tick num=1,
    tick align=outside,
            }
```

and then in document use as

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

This common settings you still can locally partly change or extend with new options, which you write into axis options. For example:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[GRID,
every axis plot post/.append style={very thick} % if this diagran should have `very thick` function curve/line.        
                    ]
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: I am deeply humbled by the depth and clarity of your responses. For someone like me who struggles mightily with understanding the package manuals, your instructions are beyond invaluable. Thank you so much!